# Browserify: How would you read the contents of a directory

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

In my current Browserify project, I need the ability to loop through the folders of a specific directory and get a json file from each. So I'll need some kind of `fs` module.

Are there any specific modules you can recommend that play nice with Browserify & will let me use `readdirsync` / `readdir` or another method to read the contents of another directory?

Apparently I can't use the normal nodejs `fs` module, and I've looked at [brfs](https://github.com/substack/brfs) but that only gives me access to `readFile`.

I would love to do something like :

```
// app.js
getFiles = require('./getFiles.js')():
```

and

```
// getFiles.js
module.exports = function(){
  var fs = require('some_module_system');

  var folders = fs.readdir('../path/to/dir', function(err, contents){
    console.log(contents);
  });
}
```

and wrap it all up with

```
browserify app.js > build.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [brfs](https://github.com/substack/brfs) browserify transform.  It has readdir and readdirSync (and all the other fs stuff too).

First install brfs:

```
npm install --save brfs
```

then replace your 'some_module_system' with the normal 'fs' module (brfs transform will process that out when you call browserify).

After that:

```
browserify -t brfs app.js > build.js
```

and you're good to go.